# Why is Quadro slower than GTX rendering on GPU cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, rendering

Will Blender Cycles have a better performance in the future with Nvidia Quadro?

Comment: Hardware related questions are off-topic here. The reason being questions are usually extremely localized and in most cases non-constructive. You can see http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/12

Comment: I don't think the statement that Quadro is slower than GTX cards is true in general. You have to look at the specifications of the individual cards to compare, both have many variations at different price and performance points, just because it's a Quadro doesn't mean it has better specifications.

Answer (score 7):

Quadro cards tend to have less CUDA cores than GTX cards, therefore their performance is worse.
The advantage of using a Quadro or Tesla cards consists in more GPU memory (which means more complex renders).

For more info you can check out the nVidia website and look at the specs of the cards.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro):

> In introducing Quadro, NVIDIA was able to charge a premium for essentially the same graphics hardware in professional markets, and direct resources to properly serve the needs of those markets. To differentiate their offerings, NVIDIA used driver software and firmware to selectively enable features vital to segments of the workstation market; e.g., high performance anti-aliased lines and two-sided lighting were reserved for the Quadro product.

Thus the [GTK 680](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-680/specifications) and [Quadro K5000](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-k5000.html#pdpContent=2) will render at the same speed. As they are based on the same hardware.